# PHP: <script> tag echoed from $_POST is mysteriously blocked

Tags: php, javascript, security, xss

I'm trying to test information I learned regarding PHP security. I have a simple HTML5 page with a POST form and a single textarea input, where I input the following JS code:

```
<script>var x = 5; alert(x);</script>
```

In the receiving PHP page, I simply `echo $_POST['varname'];` to see the JS code executed. This is of course the first step in trying to sanitize the input.

...but it doesn't work! The HTML code I get back is literally

```
<doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<script>var P = 3; alert(P);</script></body>
</html>
```

... but the alert doesn't run! the more curious thing is that when I copy the code as it is into the PHP file and let it just return this code without using PHP, it doesn't run again, but then if I change the name of the variable or its value - it runs!

This happens both on Chrome and Safari. I checked out the sent and received headers and could not find anything suspicious.

Does anyone know what is this weird voodoo magic? because I'm losing my mind here.

Comment: doctype should have "!" as in <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: what does console say, are there any js errors

Comment: i already tried it but it works

Comment: That is weird really...

Comment: better try to run it in `firefox`..

Comment: Workaround: Do not write <script> and </script> in input area add them at the php echo. And stop banging your head to walls, you will need it, it is precious...;)

Comment: Thanks pd4627, I forgot about the exclamation mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run your code and on the chrome's console it says

"Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found within request."

So It might be a natural security measure, nothing wrong with the code.

The behaviour may vary from browser to browser because of the different approaches from them

Comment: as far as I know scripts coming from the same origin as the page are supposed to be trusted , no ?

Comment: It seems that it's not trusted, I don't really know it, my answer is just based on experience, I mean, I'm not an expert, but I just tried it and that was the console log's message.

Comment: Thanks, I did not check the console, that's what it is showing for me too. Interesting security feature, although it is preventing me from doing my security testing! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.
This is a security feature of WebKit itself - that is why both Chrome and Safari had it. To prevent certain forms of XSS attacks, it blocks the page from executing JS code that was sent in the request header.
The way to bypass this is to send the response header

```
x-xss-protection: 0
```

and now all my fake malicious code works maliciously well.